# Press a in game Button to play a animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently thought about adding a InGame Button to my Game. It's not a GUI or UI Button, it's a Block, added to a Wall for example.

Dummy Code:

```
OnTriggerEnter(c:Collider)  { 
    if(c.gameObject.tag =="Player") 
    {
       //Text = "E to interact!" 

      if(key.pressed("e")
      {
         //Connect the Button to a specific Block,      play a Animation
      } 
    }  
 }
```

So how do I connect a specific Block to the Button, and if I press e, Play the Animation just on the specific block? Please keep in mind that I'm new in Unity. 
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: can you please elaborate more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you already managed to create your animation, so I-ll explain from scratch. When in the editor, select your Door and press ctrl+6 to open the animation window. From here you can animate your block. When you will be done creating the **animation**, your block object will have a new script attached to it: an **animator**. You can see the animator state machine in the animator window

These are two different things:

- **Animation**: Defines a single animation (translation, rotation, change of color, ...)
- **Animator**: defines when an animation occurs for the corresponding gameobject. An animator can have variables (for example, a bool) that define which is the next animation to be played

Any object can have an animator (your button can have one to move when it is pressed. You door can have another one to open / close)

For instance, in your button animator, you should have three states: Idle, Press, UnPress.
The state Press will contain the animation "press" with speed 1. The state UnPress will contain the animation "press with speed -1

Then, still in the animator window, You will create links between Idle and the two other states and add a trigger condition called "OnPress" (for example)

You can do the same to animate your door

In your Button code, you will then write

```
public Animator Door; // In the editor, give a reference to your door. It must have an Animator script for this to work

OnTriggerEnter(c:Collider)  { 
    if(c.gameObject.tag =="Player") 
    {
        //Text = "E to interact!" 

        if(key.pressed("e")
        {
           GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("OnPress"); // The button's animator goes to "pressed" state
           Door.SetTrigger("Open");  // The door's animator goes to "open" state
        } 
    }  
}
```

Then you could add another trigger to unpress the button

**One more thing:** When you say "Connect the button to the block", I feel like you misunderstood something: Your button script should be already added to the block in the editor

Look at these two links for more information on animations:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimatorWindow.html

Comment: Wow! That's a very long and nice answer! Thank you!  I'm not home yet, will test it and respond if it works or if I have any problems, thank you!

Comment: So my Button script has to be on the Button and the Block I want to move (Door)? Because I want to press my InGame Button and want to move the Door, but the Scripture contains the function for the ButtonBlock. I would guess I need to attach the script to both of them, or make a public gameobject and reference it?

Comment: I though what you called "block" was the visual representation of the in game button. Just to be sure I understood, You have one gameobject with a 3d mesh that looks like a button and the player can press it, and you have another gameobject with a 3d mesh that looks like a door. When the player press 'e' in front of the button, the door animates. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. A 3D Mesh of a Button, and one for the door. You can click the Button and the Door opens :) Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I just edited the answer. Basically, you give a reference of the door to the button script. The button script can call its own animator, or the door's animator, or both

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! I'm on my way home. Will give you feedback and / or mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: Okay, it works for now! 
Only problem: The Animation loops over and over again. I think that's why I should add the three states "Idle, Press, UnPress"

But how do I do that? Sorry for bothering, still new to Unity ^^

Comment: Click on the animation file in Unity (in the project explorer, where all the files are). In the inspector window, you should see an option "loop time". Uncheck it to have your anim play only once.

Comment: To learn more, play with the animator for a bit. What you can do is put the Game window next to the animator window. You will be able to see in which animation state you are in real time

Comment: Better late as never! 
I get this Error:  "There is no 'Animator' attached to the "Button" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animator to the game object "Button". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it." 

Animator and Button with Attached Animator: http://puu.sh/pVEs8/ad9af1b936.png

Also, the Code doesn't jump into the function with `Input.GetKeyDown("e"))`

Comment: Difficult to say much without seeing your code now. I think that you reproduced what I wrote. In my sample, I showed how to call two different animators. The Door (to animate a door opening) and the Button (to animate the button pressed by the player). You don't necessarily need both. Here, you didn't add an animator to the button, so the line with GetComponent<Animator> is not needed